# Haskell type family applications are not evaluated

Tags: haskell, gadt, type-families, data-kinds

I found an interesting situation, when using data kinds with type families.

The compiler's error message is `No instance for (C (ID ())) arising from a use of W`. It suggests that a type family application is not fully evaluated, even when it is saturated. `:kind! ID ()` evaluates to `()`, so according to the `C ()` instance should be used.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

type family ID t where
  ID t = t

class C t where
instance C () where

data W where
  W :: C (AppID t) => P t -> W

type family AppID t where
  AppID t = (ConstID t) ()

type family ConstID t where
  ConstID t = ID

data P t where
  P :: P t

data A

w :: W
w = W (P :: P A)
```

Could I somehow force the evaluation of `ID ()`? Is it a compiler bug?

I'm using GHC 7.8.3

Comment: How does (ID ()) evaluate to anything?  There are no instances for the ID family.

Comment: I wrote it as a closed type family (http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families#Closed_family_simplification)

Comment: Writing it as a normal type family does not change the error.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your code carefully enough.  Yeah, it looks like it should work.

Comment: Eta-expanding `ConstID t` seems to work. Maybe there is some bug in the handling of partially applied type families as in `ID`. (Honestly, I thought these were disallowed. Did we effectively get type-level lambdas lately?)

Comment: As I see, most of what can be done on term level can also be done on type level. It's nice, isn't it?

Comment: I say it's a bug.  Also, try `y = case W (P :: P A) of W P -> "hi"` and weep at the resulting absurd error.

Comment: Something more: if I leave the type signature `w :: W` it compiles. When I ask the type of w, it gives `w :: W`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the kind of `ConstID`.

```
type family ConstID t a where
  ConstID t a = ID a
```